# Catching exception but browser still shows error page

Tags: aiohttp

I have a handler that is more or less this:

```
async def handler(request):
    response = web.StreamResponse(headers={
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    })
    response.enable_chunked_encoding()
    await stream_response.prepare(request)
    try:
        await do_a_thing(response) # writes into response
    except Exception as e:
        # log the exception. I sometimes catch a CancelledError here
    await response.write_eof()
    return response
```

When nothing goes wrong, the page is generated fine.
When a CancelledError occurs in do_a_thing(), the browser shows an error page ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING, even though:

- the CancelledError is definitely NOT happening on writing the response (it's during an HTTP GET to another URL in do_a_thing())
- I catch the exception
- I don't do anything different to write the EOF and return the response

I must be doing something wrong, or not doing something right, but I can't tell what.

Can anyone see what it might be?

Comment: Not exactly sure what the problem is but I would try calling [await response.drain()](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.StreamResponse.drain) before returning or between `write` calls, also I don't think `await response.write_eof()` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah from example code write_eof() is maybe not needed. I do await drain() after each write. It works fine except when I see CancelledError.

Comment: Ok, can't really help more without seeing do_a_thing.